# Swift keyboard appear to textfield move not working properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create when keyboard appear respective textfield should move top of the keyboard, Here two things I need to solve, while editing time textfield gone to the starting point also I need to use below code within subclass because want to get reference by multiple other classes textfield.

Here, Below my code

```
extension UIView {

    func bindToKeyboard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    func unbindFromKeyboard(){
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    @objc
    func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {

        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

        let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        let curFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let targetFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = targetFrame.origin.y - curFrame.origin.y

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        })
    }
}
```

In Viewdidload

```
baseview.bindToKeyboard()
```

textfield should return

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.baseview.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using this framework, it will help you a lot effort:

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

      return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro I need some code in that way i can understand more...@koingDev

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly working. Try this

```
// Start Editing The Text Field
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    moveTextField(textField, moveDistance: -100, up: true)
}

// Finish Editing The Text Field
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    moveTextField(textField, moveDistance: -100, up: false)
}

// Hide the keyboard when the return key pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

// Move the text field in a pretty animation!
func moveTextField(_ textField: UITextField, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool) {
    let moveDuration = 0.3
    let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)

    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```